Modal breaks when Swipeable element is rendered on the page
in my main page if the Swipeable elements are not rendered my modal works correctly.enter image description here
but when they get rendered the modal breaks and its un-interactable (when I force it to be in the middle of the page).
enter image description here
the modal is the thing in the top left of the screen.
index code
   <>
      <Popup
        visible={visible}
        setVisible={setVisible}
        addToDoList={addToDoList}
      />
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Header title={'Todo List'} />
        <View style={styles.buttonArea}>
          <TouchableHighlight
            style={styles.buttonStyle}
            onPress={() => {
              setVisible(true);
              console.log(toDoList);
            }}
            underlayColor="green"
          >
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Add Item</Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.content}>
          <ListComponent
            data={toDoList}
            toggleTaskDone={toggleTaskDone}
            deleteToDoList={deleteToDoList}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    </>

modal (popup) code
  <Modal
      animationType="fade"
      transparent
      visible={visible}
      onRequestClose={() => setVisible(false)}
    >
      <GestureHandlerRootView>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <GestureDetector gesture={pan}>
            <Animated.View style={[styles.popupContent, animatedStyle]}>
              <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.label}>To Do Item</Text>
                <TextInput
                  style={styles.input}
                  placeholder="Enter title"
                  onChangeText={(text) => setValue({ ...value, title: text })}
                  value={value.title}
                />
                <Text style={styles.label}>Importance</Text>
                {/* Use Picker component for importance */}
                <View style={styles.pickerBorder}>
                  <Picker
                    selectedValue={value.importance}
                    style={styles.picker}
                    onValueChange={(itemValue) =>
                      setValue({ ...value, importance: itemValue })
                    }
                    placeholder="Select Importance"
                  >
                    <Picker.Item label="Select Importance" value="" />
                    <Picker.Item label="High" value="High" />
                    <Picker.Item label="Medium" value="Medium" />
                    <Picker.Item label="Low" value="Low" />
                  </Picker>
                </View>
              </View>
              <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={pressHandler}>
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Submit</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </Animated.View>
          </GestureDetector>
        </View>
      </GestureHandlerRootView>
    </Modal>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  popupContent: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderRadius: 20,
    padding: 35,
    alignItems: 'center',
    shadowColor: '#000',
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
    shadowOpacity: 0.25,
    shadowRadius: 4,
    elevation: 5,
    width: '80%',
  },
  inputContainer: {
    width: '100%',
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
  label: {
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
  input: {
    height: 55,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#ccc',
    borderRadius: 5,
    padding: 10,
    marginBottom: 10,
    width: '100%',
    fontSize: 17,
  },
  picker: {
    height: 55,
    padding: 10,
    width: '100%',
  },
  pickerBorder: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#ccc',
    borderRadius: 5,
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
  button: {
    backgroundColor: '#007bff',
    borderRadius: 5,
    paddingVertical: 10,
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
  },
  buttonText: {
    color: 'white',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});


Swipeable (ListComponent) code
 <View style={styles.container}>
      {data && data.length !== 0 ? (
        <FlatList
          data={data}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <Swipeable
              ref={swipeableRef}
              friction={3}
              overshootLeft={false}
              overshootRight={false}
              leftThreshold={50}
              rightThreshold={50}
              renderRightActions={() => (
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => deleteToDoList(item)}>
                  <Animated.Text>
                    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                    Velit dolor ipsam deserunt possimus, laudantium voluptate
                    dolorem repudiandae ipsa omnis eum accusamus, iste qui
                    voluptatibus quas aliquid aspernatur cupiditate natus neque?
                  </Animated.Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              )}
              renderLeftActions={() => (
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={close}>
                  <Animated.Text>
                    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                  </Animated.Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              )}
              onSwipeableWillOpen={(direction) => {
                console.log(direction);
              }}
            >
              <Animated.View style={{}}>
                <TouchableOpacity
                  activeOpacity={0.8}
                  onPress={() =>
                    toggleTaskDone({ id: item.id, done: item.done })
                  }
                >
                  <LinearGradient
                    colors={[
                      '#f9f9f9',
                      '#f9f9f9',
                      '#f9f9f9',
                      getImportanceColor(item.importance),
                    ]}
                    end={[1.003, 0]}
                    style={{
                      ...styles.itemContainer,
                      borderColor: getImportanceColor(item.importance),
                    }}
                  >
                    <View style={styles.checkboxContainer}>
                      <View
                        style={[
                          styles.checkbox,
                          item.done && styles.checkboxDone,
                        ]}
                      >
                        {item.done && (
                          <Text style={styles.checkboxText}>✔</Text>
                        )}
                      </View>
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.textContainer}>
                      <Text
                        style={{
                          ...styles.itemText,
                          ...(item.done ? styles.doneText : {}),
                        }}
                      >
                        {item.title}
                      </Text>
                    </View>
                  </LinearGradient>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </Animated.View>
            </Swipeable>
          )}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        />
      ) : (
        <View style={styles.noDataArea}>
          <Text style={styles.noDataText}>No data yet ☹️</Text>
          <Text style={styles.noDataText}>Please Add Some</Text>
        </View>
      )}
    </View>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    padding: 10,
  },
  itemContainer: {
    marginBottom: 8,
    padding: 10,
    borderWidth: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#f9f9f9',
    borderRadius: 5,
    shadowColor: '#000',
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
    shadowOpacity: 0.1,
    shadowRadius: 5,
    elevation: 0, 
    minHeight: 60, 
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center', 
  },
  checkboxContainer: {
    marginRight: 10,
  },
  checkbox: {
    width: 24,
    height: 24,
    borderRadius: 5,
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: '#333',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  checkboxDone: {
    backgroundColor: '#4CAF50',
    borderColor: '#4CAF50',
  },
  checkboxText: {
    fontSize: 18,
    color: 'white',
  },
  textContainer: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  doneText: {
    textDecorationLine: 'line-through',
    textDecorationStyle: 'solid',
    color: '#888',
  },
  itemText: {
    fontSize: 16,
    color: '#333',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  importanceText: {
    fontSize: 14,
    color: '#555',
  },
  noDataText: {
    fontSize: 26,
    color: '#888',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  noDataArea: {
    height: '90%',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});


I tried giving each element their own GestureHandlerRootView and and right now the whole Stack is enclosed with GestureHandlerRootView.
is there a way to get this to work correctly, or am I going at it the wrong way
